# Things to keep in mind when calling R functions from within nested lists

Tags: r, list, function, organization, r-package

Is it expensive to organize my `R` `functions` inside nested `lists` and then call them in different parts of the package? For instance, let's say I have the following pseudo code:

```
ThetaEstimates <- list(

    # different approaches to estimate WLE
    collection.wle = list(
        via.package.x = function(...) {
            stop("not implemented")
        },

        via.package.y = function(...) {
            stop("not implemented")
        },

        via.cpp = function(...) {
            stop("not implemented")
        }
    ),


    # different approaches to estimate WL
    collection.wl = list(
        # same as above
    ),


    # different approaches to estimate EAP
    collection.eap = list(
        # same as above
    )

) # ThetaEstimates
```

Then, I would like to call these functions inside exported `functions` or inside `R6Class` `initialize()` like:

```
Estimator = R6::R6Class("Estimator",
    # public
    public = list(
        initialize = function(method) {
            if (methods == "WLE") {
                ThetaEstimates$collection.wle$via.mirt()
            } else if(...) {
                # and so on
            } else {
                # and so on
            }
        }
    )
) # Estimator
```

I've been looking around but I can't find an opinionated answer on the topic. From browsing different repositories on `GitHub` I noticed that most people prefer to have the `functions` in `utils.R` files, all in the same place. However, I am concerned this might be hard to deal with later when more and more `functions` will be added. Specifically, my questions are:

- Are there performance bottlenecks in organizing and calling `functions` from nested `lists`?
- What are some good resources or repositories to consult for understanding how to better organize an `R` package?

I hope the question is not too vague or broad (I will add more details if needed). Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'd pay some "penalty" for the `$` lookup but I can't imagine that would really impact your performance. Right now I would consider this question broad and opinion-based. It's easier to answer questions when you have a specific problem where we can provide a test-able solution.